# How to access ManyToManyField value from django signal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I have a following model and function `signal_task` which just outputs the `test_users` field objects on signal `post_save`

```
class Test_Model(models.Model):
    test_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def signal_task(self):
        print(self.test_users.all())
```

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Test_Model)
def Test_signal(sender,instance=None,created=False,**kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.signal_task()
```

- On Creating `Test_Model` objects, `singal_task()` executes which should output the `User` objects assigned to `test_users`, But it outputs the empty queryset  `<QuerySet []>`  , How do i output the `test_users` value?

Comment: By that time the `ManyToManyField` does not contain any elements. Django will first create the object (triggering `pre_save` and `post_save`), and *then* add elements to the m2m relation. It can not do that differently since as long as it is not saved, it does not have a primary key for the "through" table.

Comment: You can use `m2m_changed`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed